# Variable not defined outside .each function

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
success: function (xml) {
    $(xml).find('persons').each(function(){ 
    var html ='<div class = .... things here>'
    });
    $('body').append($(html));
}
```

It says that html is undefined? what is wrong with this?

Comment: javascript is function scoped language, just declare html before each loop. BTW, your syntax is wrong for each loop here

Comment: Also probably typo : close the each function `});`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few things to address in your code:

- You need to declare the variable outside of the function passed to `each()`.
- If your appending to the string, you'll need the `+=` operator.
- You are trying to make a jQuery object out of a string of DOM objects for `append()`; just append the string.
- You aren't closing your `each()` method. (Spotted by [Anton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21730481/variable-not-defined-outside-each-function/21730548#comment32862861_21730481))

```
success: function (xml) {
    var html = '';
    $(xml).find('persons').each(function(){ 
        html += '<div class = .... things here>'
    })
    $('body').append(html);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you declare your vairable in the `.each` function try this:

```
success: function (xml) {
    var html = "";
    $(xml).find('persons').each(function(){ 
    html ='<div class = .... things here>'
    }
  $('body').append($(html));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make variable html global or outside the loop where you want to use it.and for appending,you would need `+=` operator.something like this:

```
 success: function (xml) {
var html ="";
$(xml).find('persons').each(function(){ 
html +='<div class = .... things here>'
}
$('body').append($(html));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's local variable to the function so it can not be accessed outside.

```
success: function (xml) {
    $(xml).find('persons').each(function(){ 
    var html ='<div class = .... things here>' //scope is limited to each function block
    }
    $('body').append($(html)); // not accessible here
}
```

---

Make your variable global

without using `var` keyword it becomes global

---

or

```
success: function (xml) {
    var html; //make it global.
    $(xml).find('persons').each(function(){ 
       html +='<div class = .... things here>';
    }
    $('body').append($(html)); // not accessible here
}
```

Comment: here `html` is still undefined when appending it. Anonymous function of each loop create its own scope

Answer (score 1):

That has to do with how the variable is viewed by the code. Simplefied there are two types, global and local. Small piece of code to explain.

```
var ThisWillBeGlobal = 'hello';
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Here I can access 'ThisWillBeGlobal ', because it has been defined out of the loop
    console.log( ThisWillBeGlobal ); // Proof :)

    var definedInsideOfFunction = 'Magic right here';
    console.log( definedInsideOfFunction ); // This will work. Defined in functions, usable in function
});
// This will work:
console.log( ThisWillBeGlobal ); // it has been defined outside the functions

// This wont work, because it's not globally defined, it only exists in the function above
console.log( definedInsideOfFunction );
```

In your code that would make this:

```
success: function (xml) {
    var html; // By creating the var out of the loop, it's global.
    $(xml).find('persons').each(function(){ 
    html ='<div class = .... things here>'; // don't define var here, it won't be accessable outside this looped function
    }
    $('body').append( html);
}
```